# Need Pure/jQuery Javascript Solution For Cleaning Word HTML From Text Area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ms-word

I know this issue has been touched on here but I have not found a viable solution for my situation yet, so I'd like to but the brain trust back to work and see what can be done.

I have a textarea in a form that needs to detect when something is pasted into it, and clean out any hidden HTML & quotation marks. The content of this form is getting emailed to a 3rd party system which is particularly bitchy, so sometimes even encoding it to the html entity characters isn't going to be a safe bet.

I unfortunately cannot use something like FCKEditor, TinyMCE, etc, it's gotta stay a regular textarea in this instance. I have attempted to dissect FCKEditor's paste from word function but have not had luck tracking it down.

I am however able to use the jQuery library if need be, but haven't found a jQuery plugin for this just yet.

I am specifically looking for information geared towards cleaning the information pasted in, not how to monitor the element for change of content.

Any constructive help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am looking at David Archer's answer and he pretty much answers it.  I have used in the past a solution similar to his:

```
$("textarea").change( function() {
    // convert any opening and closing braces to their HTML encoded equivalent.
    var strClean = $(this).val().replace(/</gi, '&lt;').replace(/>/gi, '&gt;');

    // Remove any double and single quotation marks.
    strClean = strClean.replace(/"/gi, '').replace(/'/gi, '');

    // put the data back in.
    $(this).val(strClean);
});
```

If you are looking for a way to completely REMOVE HTML tags

```
$("textarea").change( function() {
    // Completely strips tags.  Taken from Prototype library.
    var strClean = $(this).val().replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '');

    // Remove any double and single quotation marks.
    strClean = strClean.replace(/"/gi, '').replace(/'/gi, '');

    // put the data back in.
    $(this).val(strClean);
});
```

Comment: I wish I knew RegEx, so I could write a sollution as easy as this (:

Answer (score 5):

You could check out [Word HTML Cleaner](http://ethilien.net/websoft/wordcleaner/cleaner.htm) by Connor McKay. It is a pretty strong cleaner, in that it removes a lot of stuff that you might want to keep, but if that's not a problem it looks pretty decent.

Comment: A better one I've found that doesn't strip newlines and other critical formatting is: http://jhy.io/tools/convert-word-to-plain-text

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
function cleanHTML(pastedString) {
    var cleanString = "";
    var insideTag = false;
    for (var i = 0, var len = pastedString.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (pastedString.charAt(i) == "<") insideTag = true;
        if (pastedString.charAt(i) == ">") {
            if (pastedString.charAt(i+1) != "<") {
                insideTag = false;
                i++;
            }
        }
        if (!insideTag) cleanString += pastedString.charAt(i);
    }
    return cleanString;
}
```

Then just use the event listener to call this function and pass in the pasted string.

Comment: Does that still work if there are unmatched < or > signs in html comments?

Answer (score 1):

It might be useful to use the blur event which would be triggered less often:

```
$("textarea").blur(function() {
    // check input ($(this).val()) for validity here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited from the jquery docs..

```
$("textarea").change( function() {
    // check input ($(this).val()) for validity here
});
```

Thats for detecting the changes.  The clean would probably be a regex of sorts

edited above to look for a textarea not a textbox

Comment: I'm familiar with how to monitor a paste action into the textarea, but I really need something more to do with actually cleaning the content. Thanks though.