# CKEditor - remove script tag with data processor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, data-processing

I am quite new with CKEditor (starting to use it 2 days ago) and I am still fighting with some configuration like removing the  tag from editor.

So for example, if a user type in source mode the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert('hello');</script>
```

I would like to remove it.

Looking the documentation, I found that this can be done using an HTML filter. I so defined it but it does not work.

```
var editor = ev.editor;
var dataProcessor = editor.dataProcessor;
var htmlFilter = dataProcessor && dataProcessor.htmlFilter;
htmlFilter.addRules(
    {
        elements :
          {
             script : function(element)
                {
                   alert('Found script :' + element.name);
                   element.remove();
                },
             img : function( element )
                {
                   alert('Found script :' + element.name);
                   if ( !element.attributes.alt )
                       element.attributes.alt = 'Cookingfactory';
                   }
                 }
             });
```

The img part is working well but not the script one. I guess I missed something. It even does not display the alert message for script.

Any help would be more than welcome :o)

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391288/client-side-javascript-code-to-strip-bogus-html-from-ckeditor

Comment: Andrea,Thx for trying to help. Not sure how the link is supposed to help (maybe I do not understant all) but do you have any idea why the solution I tried is not working?

Comment: no, don't know htmlFilter. But what you want to achieve is "stripping html tags from source in CKEditor"; the link i posted is about "strip bogus HTML from CKEditor". The solution accepted suggests to use the integrated cleanUp function of CKEditor, no need to build one by yourself... have you tried that solution ?

Comment: I just tried and it does not look like to work. Also it looks it's doing more than what I want. Advantages of the htmlfilter solution is that you do define what to do with specific tag. Not sure of what does the pastefromword cleaning tool.

Comment: Ah it's working when I use the save button. But still, I do not know what does completely this process. I would prefer to understand why the htmlfilter is not working (it seems to be the right method to do such a thing).

Comment: Ok, it works but it works "too much". Then this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912805/how-to-define-allowed-tags-in-ckeditor could be the solution :)

Comment: forcePasteasPlainText -> this is when you do a paste in the editor. removeFormatTags -> this is for the remove format icon :o(

Comment: Mmm you're right sorry... i think htmlFilter does not caught script, i've looked at the source code of CKE a bit and the script tags are only 'protected', but they'll output the same... i guess the easiest solution is to decode them after the output, or to modify CKE source code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this :

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
   on: {
      pluginsLoaded: function(event) {
         event.editor.dataProcessor.dataFilter.addRules({
            elements: {
               script: function(element) {
                  return false;
               }
            }
         });
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: I tired your code, when go to the "Source" mode and add script tag, then go back to "design" mode, the script tag is not removed.
At what point the script tag is supposed to be removed?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CKEditor 4.1 or above, you may use [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) to allow the content you want.

If you are using CKEditor 4.4 or above, there is an easier way. You can use [Disallowed Content](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_disallowed_content) to filter content you don't like .

```
 config.disallowedContent = 'script';
```

Answer (score 0):

As I'm having CKEditor 4, I did the next

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.config.protectedSource.push( /{.*\".*}/g );
```

It will ignore quotes in smarty curly brackets