# Removing external styles from jQuery WYSIWYG editor in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, editor, text-editor, wysiwyg

I have an issue with my WYSIWYG editor. If users copy in outside text, this is seen as something like the following:

> " p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px
>   0.0px; font: 11.0px 'Lucida Grande'; min-height: 13.0px} p.p2 {margin:
>   0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 11.0px 'Lucida Grande'} Only the variables
>   assigned in the last loop are
>   accessible from outside the scope of a
>   foreach loop."

This is obviously problematic.

On top of that, there also seems to be an issue with line breaks, i.e. `<br />` tags. Sometimes they're picked up, sometimes not.

I've been running the content through `strip_tags()` like so:

```
<?php
$body = strip_tags($body, '<a><br><b><i><img><ul><ol><li>');
```

Any thoughts on what's going on here?

If it helps, I'm using jWYSIWYG for the editor.

Comment: Please clarify if you are doing anything to the editor's content with jQuery? If so, please provide details

Comment: No. The editor's content is within an iFrame and so is sorely inaccessible to jQuery, except through the jWYSIWYG editor itself. I can only access the content through its own getContent and setContent methods.

Comment: I'm not sure if I have misunderstood you, but you can access the content from the parent, e.g. $('#wysiwyg-frame').contents().find('body #wysiwyg').val(). Are you able to post code/a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code finally got it working for me:

```
$('iframe').ready(function() {
    $(this).contents().find('.wysiwyg').find('iframe').contents()
    .find('.wysiwyg').bind('paste', function() {
        // Completely strips tags.  Taken from Prototype library.
        var el = $(this);
            var strClean = el.text().replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '');
            el.text(strClean);
        }, 0);
    });
});
```

You can see this in action at http://jsfiddle.net/v4LhV/3/

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your query about **strip_tags()**:

```
php > $str="<br><br/><br />";
php > echo strip_tags($str, "<br>");
<br><br />
```

Is there a chance that `<br/>` is used and being omitted? If so, add `<br/>` to strip_tags(), e.g.

```
php > $str="<br><br/><br />";
php > echo strip_tags($str,'<br><br/>');
<br><br/><br />
```

Comment: Good thought to include `<br/>` and `<br />`. Unfortunately, that seems to change nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use preg_replace like http://ideone.com/VjMZY?

```
$str = preg_replace('/<br[^\>]*?>/', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue tracker for jwysiwg has comments related to this for browser side cleanup.

- [Issue #32 stripping tags from Word](https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg/issues#issue/32): mentions reverting to previous text if word formats get pasted

  > So instead I suggest observing for a paste event. On paste, check if the content contains any hidden Word markup. If yes, alert the user and restore the text to its pre-paste state.
- [Issue #23 links to stack overflow: need-pure-jquery-javascript-solution-for-cleaning-word-html-from-text-area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038129/need-pure-jquery-javascript-solution-for-cleaning-word-html-from-text-area)
  '